# HyperLink in GridView

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview set up that contains information about accommodation. Each row then has a link to view more information. On that page information about that accommodation is displayed with a further link to view comments based on the accommodationid. When viewing those comments I want a way to go back to the accommodation viewed without just clicking the back button on the browser.

So basically I need a hyperlink that looks at the accommodation ID wither from the url or the detailsview shown and goes to something like this sort of link where the ID changes depending on what accommodation your viewing:

http://localhost:9000/WebSite1/comments.aspx?Accom_ID=1001

Any ideas how?

Update: Thanks for the responses but I want a link at the bottom of the page not on each row of the gridview. Also the page changes based on what is show so I cant just put a hyperlink to ...accom_id=1001 as sometimes its another ID.

Comment: Obviously we can't access your site at "localhost:9000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<GidView runat="server">
    ..
    <HyperLinkField Text="Comments" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Comments.aspx?id={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" />
</GidView>
```

---

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="urlComments" Text="Comments" />
```

and

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    urlComments.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Comments.aspx?id={0}", this.Request.QueryString["Accom_ID"]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I realise I can put a link in each gridview row using that code but I want a single link that does not need to within the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on page `/WebSite1/comments.aspx?Accom_ID=1001`, then just set the hyperlink URL to `/WebSite1/accomodation.aspx?Accom_ID=1001`

This is how the NavigateURL should be set:

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    urlComments.NavigateUrl = "~/accomodation.aspx?Accom_ID=" + Request.QueryString["Accom_ID"];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know you cant access my site at local host, I need a link that dynamically updates based on the page your viewing. I dont have a page for each accommodation therefore the link needs to change based on what the user is viewing.

Comment: @Mark, you know you can set the NavigateUrl in the code on page load so that it is different for each item.

Comment: In general, everything fine with your code. But `Page_Load` can't be `override`; it's better to use `Onxxx` rather then `Page_xxx`;  and culture-neutral formatting should be faster then string concatenation. Cheers! :)

Comment: @abatishchev, overloading an average page is going to be exceedingly rare, so using the default Visual Studio generated method won't be a problem.  Furthermore, worrying about the speed of the string concatenation here is nonsense.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's a big problem, my just a style to follow best practice.